# bash script - I want to check if XLS is empty. if it is, i don't want to do anything. If it is not, I want to do something

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I have a bash script that has an if-then-fi statement included. the code block executes only when the XLS is not empty. Currently i'm evaluating this by utilizing the following:

```
FILESIZE = `wc -c < $FILENAME`
```

it seems that the default filesize generated is 4096 bytes if the file is empty. So...

```
if [ $FILESIZE -gt "4096" ]; then
do something
fi
```

however, my boss isn't a huge fan of hard coded numbers. is there an alternative solution to seeing whether an XLS has data?

thanks!

Comment: Generate an empty file and compare them?

Comment: Using something like `stat` or `du` is likely more appropriate than `wc` for this purpose as well (though it appears that `-c` is smart enough not to actually read the entire file).

Comment: I tested out with stat as well and received 4096 bytes. I was actually going to switch it but now the plan is to get rid of the method all together. I'm pretty new to the environment. could you elaborate on empty file generation and comparing?

Comment: That was mostly tongue-in-cheek. If you don't want to hardcode the size of an empty `XLS` file then you can generate an empty one and compare other files against it (either on the fly or store an empty one for comparison). Neither of those is a particularly good idea though. A tool that can query `XLS` files is a better option if you have one available.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ -r "$FILENAME ]    # If there is a readable file "$FILENAME"
then
    if [ -s "$FILENAME" ]  # If file "$FILENAME" has a size greater than zero bytes
    then
        do something
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would this address the issue though? because, like i mentioned, a blank isn't zero. when i run l -ltr on my archived reports i notice that all blank xls files are 4096 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You could to use xls2csv command, if result is 0 the file is empty.

```
xls2csv file.xls | wc -l
```

This command it's usually in the "catdoc" package.

Comment: does this convert the xls?

Comment: this command convert xls into csv and output the result by stdout.

Comment: @tbermeo you need catdoc package installed.